# Import multiple PDF's from Multiple folders, into a SQL table.

Tags: sql, mysqli, ssis, ssis-2012

I need to upload multiple PDF files from Multiple Folders (a shared directory) into a SQL table. what is the best way to complete this task and have it automated? The DB Table structure looks like this> [DB table format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8wyD.gif)

the **file list** is the full path. the **type** is the folder, where file came from, the **File name** is the file name and Ext. 
The files in the shared folders are scanned PDF's. 17 folders deep.
[PDF's in one folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqqPE.gif)
the Shared Tree looks like this: 
[folder tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/627TQ.gif)
This use to be done with a stored procedure, where the DB table would be deleted (as another task scans the table and hashes the pdf's into a CMR) and the shared folders scanned and imported into the table. This has failed with the fail point being xp_cmdshell and I have went down that route adding proxy and it still fails the command. there must be a better way to upload the Multiple PDFs from those folders and then delete the files from the folders after they have been moved.
any suggestions? or point me in the correct direction?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Your question seems to imply you'd like to store the actual .pdf files in a database table, but your `DB table format` image suggests that you're only storing the path to the file.

Comment: It is not possible to help, as we do not know what your actual setup does. The Information that xp_cmdshell fails is not sufficient, as you did not tell aus where you used it and what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Sorry look at it again, yes the files path is stored and then something takes the list from the DB table and goes and gets the PDF from the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to start by creating two string variables. The first will contain the path to your shared folder tree's base folder. I've called mine `PathToBaseFolder`. The second will be used to store the current file's full path. I've called mine `FullyQualifiedFilePath`. No need to give it a value now.
[image]

Next, you'll want to create a `Foreach Loop Container`. For the Enumerator, choose `Foreach File Enumerator`. Next, expand `Expressions`, and add a new expression for the `Directory` property. Set the expression to be your variable you created above.
[image]

Click `Ok`, and go back to the task editor. Under `Enumerator configuration`, set your file mask to `*.pdf`, and make sure `Fully qualified` and `Traverse subfolders` are both checked. You don't need to change the `Folder` since the expression we defined above will be used at runtime, but you can if you want. Your `Collection` tab should now look like this:
[image]

Click on the `Variable Mappings` tab on the left of the loop editor window. Click the blank rectangle under `Variable` and select your file path variable, and make sure it gets set to Index 0.

[image]

Click `Ok` in the loop editor window. Now you have a loop task that will give you the full path to every *.pdf under \network-machine\shared_folder. Each iteration of the loop will change the value of the `FullyQualifiedFilePath` variable.

From this point, if you just want to store the file path in to the table from your first paragraph, you'd create an `Execute SQL` task inside your loop, and use your file path variable as one of the inputs.

Saving a .pdf as a BLOB into a database table will be similar, but most likely you'll have to use a Script Task to load each .pdf into memory and then insert the BLOB.